# How to to fit the image size to device screen size without losing image quality?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to do a wallpaper application in android. I couldn't set the image to device screen size. And also the image losing its quality when i set it as wallpaper. I also tried some stackoverflow answers but those did not give me the proper result.

Here is my code:

```
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager= WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

           DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            // get the height and width of screen
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imgflag.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                if(bitmap!=null)
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you try to set thumbnail (scaled) image to the screen.

Try this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactoty.decodeFile(path); // or decodeResource, decodeStream, etc
    // depends on your source
```

instead of:

```
Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imgflag.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

This source must contain the large bitmap.